# cakePHP: how to use an action from one controller in another?

Tags: methods, controller, cakephp-1.3

I have a controller (A) to manage an object, in the controller I have a method that checks if `$this->Auth->user(id)` is allowed to access the object.
It is done by accessing an associated model (`$this->ModelA->ModelB->...`).

Now, in another controller (C) I need to check the same issue (for some internal logic). however, this controller's model is not associated to ModelB.
So, my problem is : how to check it?
pure SQL is possible but i prefer to avoid it.

the only way I see, is calling the method from another controller..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the logic into a method in the `AppController` so it's accessible to all controllers.
In that method, load the model if necessary:

```php
class AppController extends Controller {

    protected function isUserAllowed() {
        if (!isset($this->TheModel)) {
            $this->loadModel('TheModel');
        }

        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) thanks.
2) if the model is already loaded, it will load another instance or it's a singelton(like?)?
3) seems like it's the wrong way, since by adding it to the appC', I am loading it in every controller, while I need it only in two controllers?

Comment: @yossi Please take a better look at the example code. The model is only loaded if it does not already exist. It won't be loaded until the method is called. The method won't do anything until it is called and doesn't add any resources just by being there but not being called.

Comment: my apology - you are correct, you took care of it in the code.   **    
and it is correct foro the second question.. for some reason i saw 'isAuthorized' and not isUserAllowd .....
    ***    one last question, appController's methods are accessible as other methods through the browser address-bar? and, doeos the protected direction is supposed to solve this problem?

Comment: Indeed, `protected` *definitely* solves the problem, but maybe Cake wouldn't make AppC methods accessible to begin with. Not 100% sure about that though.